# How to make a navigation in Expression Blend 4?

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

So I created a layout in Expression Blend 4 for my Silverlight application. Now I need to create a simple navigation to navigate between pages. I have a canvas control in the layout (MainPage.xaml) and I would like the navigation buttons to just change the content of the canvas.

So if a user clicks on a navigation button for Page1.xaml, the Page1's content will be loaded into the canvas.

Could anybody give me an example how to do it? I tried using the MenuItem control but I could not understand how to use it. Now I have just used buttons but I don't know how to make a navigation from them.

Comment: So you want to be able to navigate pages in blend(don't think this is possible) or are you looking for the C#/VB code that you would use to select and load the Page1.xaml into your content pane on your main page?

Comment: I would like to be able to navigate in Blend. Why else would it be possible to create MenuItem controls in Blend if you cannot navigate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would love to be wrong about this but Im pretty sure, Blend 2,3,4 (the ones I have used)are just like windows form development your controls are not active until you actually build and run the application.
Sorry

**Edit**

To answer your comment the menuItem is a simple control that has been predefined like a button or link. The main idea with blend is to give developers and designers the ability to customize the look and feel of control layout in a similar way html uses CSS and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "Hyperlink Buttons" for your menu and display the content in a "Frame" control.